exception return about ARMcortexM4
I know that there are two ways to return from the ISR,it's BX LR or Pop PC,What's the difference between them? I think that BX LR is  PC dierctly read the value from the LR, so POP pc is ,earlier we push the exc return value to the stack and later we  pop  it to the PC?but during the whole ISR, the EXC RETURN value in LR won't change? so why we push exc return value to the stack?
is just like above,I want to know the differences
